# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(): fire callback if user says "no"?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Here's an approximation of my code:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(position) {
          // success! 
        },
        function(error) {
          // error
        },
        { timeout: 10000 }
    );
} else {
    // your browser/device doesn't support geolocation
}
```

When this code runs, the browser correctly asks the user for permission to track their physical location. If the user says "Yes", it correctly runs the function specified by the first argument ('success').

What's unclear to me is what happens when the user says "no".  In my testing so far (in Firefox 7), if the user says "no", nothing happens.  I was somewhat expecting the error callback (the second function) to run, but it doesn't.    I'm hoping to react to the user's negative reponse (by removing the link that triggers this call).

Answer (score 8):

You need to handle it in the second callback to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`, which handles problems such as the user denying their location (amongs other things).

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(fn, function(errorCode) {
    if (errorCode == 1) {
       alert('Y U NO GIVE LOCATION?');
    }
});
```

[W3C Spec](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#geolocation_interface).

[List of error codes](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#position_error_interface).

Comment: Okay, it looks like Firefox will not fire ANY callback if you give the answer "Not now":

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932758/firefox-5-geolocating-and-not-now-issue
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=675533


It will, as Alex suggestions, fire the error callback if you respond with "Never".

Comment: I can see the mozilla developer's view point on this. The page should have a default behavior if no geolocation is available, but I also think that the phrase "Not Now" is like saying "No" once, but don't remember my response later.

Comment: I think you should see "not now" as no answer, the same as if the user would ignore the popup alltogether.

Comment: so what would be a solution to this Firefox problem then? Can we do some kind of timer if the callback did not fire within 3 seconds, we fire off an alert?

Comment: @KalvinKlien That probably won't be reliable, but you could test it.

Answer (score 0):

small correction for the previous reply

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(your_success_function, function(error) {
    if (error.code == 1) {
       alert('Y U NO GIVE LOCATION?');
    }
});
```